# PHP How to save data from array to mysql using laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Im getting an array within array of 'Cylinders' data from POST:

```
Array
  (
    [serie] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1234
            [1] => 3545
        )

    [seriesap] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1234234
            [1] => 345345
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4546
            [1] => csdfwe
        )

    [admission] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04-05-2015
            [1] => 04-05-2015
        )

    [invoice] => Array
        (
            [0] => fei76867
            [1] => feiasodjf
        )
  )
```

Now, the fields inside the keys: serie, type, admission, etc dont change, but the info inside those key do change, i mean there could be even 15 items in there.

At the end i need to save to the database:

```
$cylinder            = new Cylinder();
$cylinder->serie     = ??;
$cylinder->seriesap  = ??;
$cylinder->type      = ??;
$cylinder->admission = ??;
$cylinder->invoice   = ??;
$cylinder->save
```

How can i accomplish this task and save all the cylinders?

I have tried all the foreach's that i could think of nothing seems to work.

/*edit*/

This is what Im doing so far:

```
$cyldata = $_POST['cylinder']; //this is the post from top.

$num_elements = 0;

while($num_elements < count($cyldata['serie'])){
    $cylinder = new Cylinder();
    $cylinder->serie     = $cyldata['serie'][$num_elements];
    $cylinder->type      = $cyldata['type'][$num_elements];
    $cylinder->admission = $cyldata['admission'][$num_elements];
    $cylinder->seriesap  = $cyldata['seriesap'][$num_elements];         
    $cylinder->save
    $num_elements++;

}
```

But it feels ugly, all those saves doesnt feel right. Dirty solution if you ask me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to convert you input data to another format:

```
$cyldata = $_POST['cylinder']; //this is the post from top.

$num_elements = 0;

$sqlData = array();

while($num_elements < count($cyldata['serie'])){
    $sqlData[] = array(
        'serie'         => $cyldata['serie'][$num_elements],
        'type'          => $cyldata['type'][$num_elements],
        'admission'     => $cyldata['admission'][$num_elements],
        'seriesap'      => $cyldata['seriesap'][$num_elements],
        'invoice'       => $cyldata['invoice'][$num_elements], // you miss this field, aren't you?
        'created_at'    => Carbon\Carbon::now(), // only if your table has this column
        'updated_at'    => Carbon\Carbon::now(), // only if your table has this column
    );
    $num_elements++;
}
```

Second, use the Fluent query builder to do a batch insert:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($sqlData);
```

**Note:** the `created_at` and `updated_at` appear here if your table has these field. When working with Eloquent model, these field is updated automatically. However, we do not use Eloquent, so that we have to assign the value to these field manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what forced you to use `$_POST` global array in order to receive the data from the user.

Perhaps, this is what you want.

```
/**
 * Store the form inputs in the table
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function store( Request $request ) {
    $data = Input::get();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['serie']); $i++) {
        $c            = new Cylinder();
        $c->serie     = $data['serie'][$i];
        $c->type      = $data['type'][$i];
        $c->admission = $data['admission'][$i];
        $c->seriesap  = $data['seriesap'][$i];

        $c->save(); // fixed typo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are having an array to insert the data to database, you can try the `create` method from the model:

```
Cylinder::create($array);
```

but it actually needs the `key` of the array to be the `field_name` in your database. Or you can do this with the query builder:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($array);
```

and again it is required to set the `key` of the array to be the `field_name` in your database.

Comment: I just tried this, only 1 row with no info on the Cylinders table, i dont think it works when there is an array within an array.

Comment: okay maybe with your own code it will work if you take `$cylinder = new Cylinder();` out of the while loop.