# saving array of array into database laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have gone through an earlier post [Storing Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496740/php-how-to-save-data-from-array-to-mysql-using-laravel-5) Let me firstly show what I have tried

**Code:**

```
public function createQuestions(Request $request)
{
  $elements = 0;
  while($elements < count($data["question"])) {
     $dataArray[] = array(
       question'          => $data['question'][$elements],
       'answer'            => $data['answer'][$elements],
       'questionnaire_id'  => $data['questionnaire_id'][$elements],
       'type'              => $data['type'][$elements],
       'flag'              => $data['flag'][$elements],
       'choice'              => $data['choice'][$elements],
       'created_at'    => Carbon\Carbon::now(), // only if your table has this column
       'updated_at'    => Carbon\Carbon::now(), // only if your table has this column
        );
$elements++;

}
Question::create($dataArray);

    return back()->with('message', 'Questionnaire is being created successfully'); 
}
```

The problems I am facing are different. Whenever I run the code. It throws an error

> Undefined offset: 1

secondly it throws an error

> General error: 1364 Field 'answer' doesn't have a default value. This error is being thrown for every database column.

I have declared these in fillable. Hence there should not be any issue.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'question', 'idea_id', 'answer', 'type', 'choice', 'flag',
];
```

I have changed my `app` name to `Questionnaire` May be this is the issue?

Comment: It seems there is an answer missing.

Comment: One thing was missing that is in `fillable` it should be `questionnaire_id` not `idea_id`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an answer missing.

Try something like:

```
...
'answer'            => (array_key_exists($elements,$data['answer']))?$data['answer'][$elements]:"", // default value
...
```

Honestly the best solution would be to change your migration:

```
$table->text()->default("");
```

But the problem here, seems to be a missing parameter from the post request maybe.

Comment: I have `dd` it. everything is coming fine from there and also this was working a little while ago after `undefined offset` this issue started

Comment: Can you post the array `$data`

Comment: Now the loop is working fine and data is storing in database. Thanks to you but now the issue is, it is storing the data twice and sometimes if there are `4` entries it replicate some of them and store 10 entries @Mruf

Comment: Are you sure your data is submited correctly? It doesn't seem too be an error of laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128596/discussion-between-qasim-ali-and-mruf).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Eloquent's method `insert`:

```
Question::insert($dataArray);
```

Note: this will not update or set timestamps. But you added these timestamps in your `$dataArray` manually, so you already fixed this yourself.

Comment: I have also used `insert` instead of `create` it still gives `undefined offset` error